# Comparing sublists of two lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `C22` and `D22` with many sublists. I want to compare elements of each sublist and print if it meets the criterion i.e. element of each sublist of `C22` is greater than element of each sublist of `D22`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
C22 = [[[353.856161, 417.551036, 353.856161, 353.856161, 282.754301]], [[294.983702, 294.983702]]]

D22 = [[[423.81345923, 230.97804127, 419.14952534, 316.58460442, 310.81809094]], 
       [[423.81345923, 419.14952534]]]


arcond1=[]

for i in range(0,len(C22)):
    cond1=C22[i]>D22[i]
    arcond1.append(cond1)
    cond1=list(arcond1)
print("cond 1 =",cond1)
```

The current output is

```
cond 1 = [False, False]
```

The expected output is

```
cond 1 = [[[False, True, False, True, False]], [[False, False]]]
```

Comment: Do you want to have two or three levels of nesting? In your text, you only talk about lists and sublists, but your code shows an extra level as each sublist is enclosed in another list.

Comment: arcond1 = [[C22[i][0][j] > D22[i][0][j] for j in range(0, len(C22[i][0]))] for i in range(0, len(C22))]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have 3 nesting levels, use a nested list comprehension:

```
out = [[[c3>d3 for c3, d3 in zip(c2, d2)]
        for c2, d2 in zip(c1, d1)]
       for c1, d1 in zip(C22, D22)]
```

Output: `[[[False, True, False, True, False]], [[False, False]]]`

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your issue with that: a loop in a loop in a loop

```py
C22 = [[[353.856161, 417.551036, 353.856161, 353.856161, 282.754301]], [[294.983702, 294.983702]]]

D22 = [[[423.81345923, 230.97804127, 419.14952534, 316.58460442, 310.81809094]], 
       [[423.81345923, 419.14952534]]]

final_res = []

cond = lambda a, b: a > b

for list_1, list_2 in zip(C22, D22):
  res1 = []
  for sub_list_1, sub_list_2 in zip(list_1, list_2):
    res2 = []
    for sub_sub_list_1, sub_sub_list_2 in zip(sub_list_1, sub_list_2):
      res2.append(cond(sub_sub_list_1, sub_sub_list_2))
    res1.append(res2)
  final_res.append(res1)

print(final_res)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a general approach, you can use the following function:

```
from typing import List, Union

InputType = Union[List[List], List[float]]
OutputType = Union[List[List], List[bool]]


def check_list_A_greater_than_B(A: InputType, B: InputType) -> OutputType:

    # some checks to validate input variables
    assert len(A) == len(B), "list A and B should be of same length"
    if not len(A):  # A and B are empty
        return []

    # if the list elements are sublists, we pass them through this function again
    # if they are floats, we compare them and return the results
    result = []
    for A_element, B_element in zip(A, B):
        # check if types match
        error_msg = (
            f"Element types of A ({type(A_element)}) "
            + f"should match B ({type(B_element)})"
            + f"\nA = {A} \nB= {B}"
        )
        assert type(A_element) == type(B_element), error_msg
        if isinstance(A_element, list):
            result.append(check_list_A_greater_than_B(A_element, B_element))
        elif isinstance(A_element, float):
            result.append(A_element > B_element)
        else:
            raise Exception(f"Unexpected type of A_element ({type(A_element)})")

    return result
```

This allows you to input lists with a variable number of sublists and nested levels.

Example usage (with C22 and D22 from your example):

```
check_list_A_greater_than_B(C22, D22)
```

outputs:

```
[[[False, True, False, True, False]], [[False, False]]]
```